# google-map-api3 how to remove an overlay using prototype

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I used the following two functions to project my overalays on a map:

```js
  myOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function () { }
  myOverlay.prototype.draw = function () { }
```

However, I could not fine a way to remove the overlays. The following function is supposed to do the job, but I could not make it work.

```js
  myOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function () {
      this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
      this.div_ = null;
  };
```

Could some experts help me out? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do exactly the same as you would do to remove `Marker`, `Rectangle`, or any [[image]google-maps-api-3](/questions/tagged/google-maps-api-3) object from the map:

```
myOverlay.setMap(null);
```